Do the threshold values in the results of Ordinal Logistic Regression need to be strictly increasing?
I understand that the estimates of the thresholds should be strictly increasing from here and this youtube lecture. This is because they represent the thresholds that determine which output class the latent variable (y*) falls into, i.e. if it falls between the first and second threshold then it should be in class 2, etc.

However, when I ran the regression on my use case using SM's ordered regression with logit distribution, I did not get strictly increasing thresholds/intercepts. When I visited the documention, the example given there was also not strictly increasing.

How do I interpret the values of the thresholds from the results?
This was the code used:

from statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model import OrderedModel
mod_log = OrderedModel(y,
train_df[x_predictors],
distr='logit')
res_log = mod_log.fit(method='bfgs', disp=False) res_log.summary()

Data is confidential but my results are like this
where the output variable is classes 1,2,3,4,5,6:

As you can see the intercepts are not monotonous

What are the levels of the variable? Also, they don't need to be strictly increasing, they just need to be monotonic (yours look like they are strictly decreasing, but it's hard to be sure without more info).

@PeterFlom thank you so much for taking a look. I have added a snippet of my results. am still trying to understand the interpretation, but from what I gather the intercepts have to be increasing, such that the log odds increase since CDF should increase from left to right

They don't need to be strictly increasing but they should be monotonic.
Your results do look problematic. I would first check that things are coded correctly (it's amazing how often they are not) and, then do some thinking about the levels to make sure they make sense.
Assuming not big insights from the above, I'd probably switch to a multinomial model.
